# Controlar el mismo evento en todos los TextBox de mi aplicación

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una aplicación de WindowsForms y el problema que tengo es que tengo una cantidad excesiva de TextBox y quisiera de alguna forma que sólo se pueda introducir números.

Hay una solución que es programar un método donde se analice la cadena del TextBox para saber si es número o no, pero el problema es que tengo que llamar ese método cada vez que se produzca el evento de pulsar tecla en cada uno de los TextBox.

Qué me sugieren, se puede hacer directamente con una propiedad del TextBox para restringir la entrada de antemano o existe alguna manera de capturar los eventos dentro de un contenedor e invalidarlos.

Cualquier sugerencia o solución la agradezco mucho.
Gracias de antemano.
Un saludo y Feliz Año.

Comment: La mejor solucion es crear un objecto TextBoxNuevo que herede de TextBox, a este objeto le añades el evento por defecto y luego ya te creas todos los TextBoxNuevos que quieras que tendran por defecto ese evento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes recorrer todos los controles de tipo `TextBox` (por ejemplo de un formulario) y asignarles un mismo controlador al evento `KeyPress` que filtre los caracteres no numéricos:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    void SoloNumeros(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(args.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(args.KeyChar)) args.Handled = true;
    }
    foreach (var textBox in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        textBox.KeyPress += SoloNumeros;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cómo hago eso que dices?? El método se entiende, pero cómo lo hago para cada TextBox??, sin tener que copiar y pegar 90 veces, o lo que se lo mismo, hacer la llamada al método 90 veces.

Comment: Cuando dices "Puedes recorrer todos los controles de tipo TextBox (por ejemplo de un formulario) y asignarles un mismo controlador al evento KeyPress" a qué te refieres.

Comment: El código que te he puesto de ejemplo selecciona todos los controles del formulario de tipo `TextBox`: `Controls.OfType<TextBox>()` y los recorre mediante un `foreach` para asignarles a todos el controlador al evento.

Comment: entonces donde meto el foreach, en el InitializeComponent??

Comment: No, dentro del `InitializeComponent` no. Es un método que crea el diseñador y que no deberías modificar nunca. Puedes ponerlo en el constructor del formulario a continuación de la llamada al método `InitializeComponent` para que los controles estén ya creados. Copiando el código que hay en mi ejemplo debería funcionarte.

Comment: Pues si funciona. Genial !!

Comment: Ahora, mis TextBox están dentro de un TableLayoutPanel, por eso no los cogía. Qué modificación puedo hacer para que los recorra teniendo en cuenta que están dentro de ese elemento??

Comment: No tienes más que recorrer los controles de la propiedad `Controls` del panel en lugar de la del formulario: `foreach (var textBox in tuPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())....`

Comment: Pues muchísimas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Está correcto el código, pero deberías establecer la propiedad **ShortcutsEnabled** en **false** para evitar que el usuario pegue un texto en el **TextBox**. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una función que compruebe cuando escribas que el carácter sea numérico y aplicarselo a todos los textBox que quieras. Algo así:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.'))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Ahora se lo añades a los textBox en la propiedad `KeyPress`.
Ojo, esto no evita que si copian y pegan texto en el textBox haya algún fallo, quizas lo puedes controlar siguiendo este patrón en otro método.

Comment: pero eso es justo lo que no quiero, hacerlo por cada TextBox. Quiero que me funcione para todos. Sin necesidad de hacerlo uno por uno.

Comment: Es que vas a tener que añadírselo a todos, ya sea a mano mediante su propiedad mientras lo diseñas, o bien por código en un bucle, accediendo a todos los elementos TextBox de tu panel.

Answer (score 0):

Usa reflection

```
 public static class Util
{
    public static void AsignarSoloNumeros(Control control)
    {

        var controls = GetAllTextBox(control);
        foreach (var textBox in controls)
        {
            textBox.KeyPress += delegate(object o, KeyPressEventArgs e)
            {
                if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.'))
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            };

        }
    }


    public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllTextBox(Control control)
    {
        var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
        var enumerable = controls as IList<Control> ?? controls.ToList();
        return enumerable.SelectMany(GetAllTextBox)
            .Concat(enumerable)
            .Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox));


    }
}
```

Lo usas después de la inicialización de controles

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
      Util.AsignarSoloNumeros(this);
    }
}
```